# Diferença entre '$()' e 'jQuery()'

Tags: javascript, jquery

É comum ver, em códigos que usam jQuery, referências à seletores usando o `$()`. Só que já encontrei códigos usando `jQuery()` para fazer *queries* de seleção.

Qual a diferença entre eles? Posso usar qualquer um dos dois ou tem casos específicos para uso de cada um?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O jQuery atende por ambos os nomes.

Existem diversas bibliotecas que também utilizam o cifrão `($)` como nome de alguma função principal, o que pode dar conflito com o jQuery. Chamar o jQuery pela função jQuery() deixa explícito que você se refere a essa biblioteca e não a outra como `MooTools`, por exemplo. O jQuery possui mecanismos para evitar conflito de nomes nesses casos, vide a resposta do Lucas Costa.

Na prática, você só precisa se preocupar com isso quando tiver que trabalhar com alguma biblioteca que também utilize o cifrão. Isso faz parte do dia-a-dia de muitos desenvolvedores, mas é provável que não seja o caso da maioria de nós.

Answer (score 7):

`$()` é um alias para `jQuery()`. Muitas bibliotecas javascript usam `$` como função ou nomes de variáveis assim como o jQuery faz.

Veja a referência de [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 7):

Só completando a resposta do [Lucas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197215/5878) e do [Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197217/5878), para ficar mais claro, basta verificar no código fonte da biblioteca:

```
define( [
    "../core"
], function( jQuery, noGlobal ) {

"use strict";

var

    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};

// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in AMD
// (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( !noGlobal ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}

} );
```

<sub>Trecho de código retirado do arquivo [`/src/exports/global.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports/global.js) do repositório oficial do jQuery.</sub>

Este arquivo implementa a lógica de exportação das variáveis para o contexto global. Na maioria dos casos, para aplicações simples, o trecho de código que prevalecerá será:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Demonstrando a resposta do Lucas, em que `$` é definido como alias para `jQuery`. O trecho de código anterior a esta linha tem como objetivo evitar o conflito com outras bibliotecas - perceba as variáveis `_jQuery` e `_$`.