# Para que serve o Cifrao ($) antes de uma Function no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Anres de váriaveis e functions, por exemplo:

```
$(function() {})
```

Comment: O código em questão utiliza jQuery?

Comment: Isso e relativo pode ser tanto jQuery, Prototype, ou qualquer biblioteca que faça referencia ao `$`. Embora em grande maioria seja usado pela biblioteca jQuery.

Comment: Para complementar: [vinculado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197213/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-e-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente é relacionado ao `jQuery`. Senão são somente nomes para variáveis.

`Javascript`:
O nome da variável pode começar com letras, sinal de cifrão($) e underline(_). Não são aceitos números ou outros símbolos. Quando o nome da variável for composto por mais de uma palavra não é permitido adicionar espaço entre elas e costuma-se utilizar o CamelCase, onde a primeira palavra começa com inicial minúscula e as seguintes com maiúsculas (variavelNome).
Para criar uma variável no javascript basta incluir a palavra reservada var na frente.

```
var texto;
```

Criar variáveis desta maneira é conhecido por tipagem fraca, onde não é preciso definir a natureza da informação que irá preencher a variável. Em qualquer ponto do código uma variável que continha texto pode passar a conter um número.

Em `jQuery`:
Todos os comandos do `jQuery` temos o alias `$ (cifrão)` como atalho. Podemos misturar sem problemas `JavaScript` nativo com `jQuery`. A base do `jQuery` são os Selectors ou Seletores, um seletor define em que parte do html ou tag vamos executar o nosso código `jQuery`, os selectores do `jQuery` são identicos ao do CSS, exemplo, temos uma div com a seguinte extrutura, a principio podemos selecionar esta div de duas formas no `jQuery`:

Assim `$("div")` ou `$("#divTeste")` (Usando o alias $) ou

Assim `jQuery("div")` ou `jQuery("#divTeste")` (Sem usar o alias $).

Answer (score 8):

Isso é tipico de jQuery. O `$` é o alias da biblioteca jQuery e essa função é o semelhante a `window.onload`, ou seja: corre quando o documento tiver carregado.

De qualquer maneira o `$` não tem significado especial em JavaScript. É um nome de variável normal, que é comum ser usado pelo jQuery.